# Point to an item from an array directly after it's returned by a function/method?

Tags: php, arrays, encapsulation

I need to be able to view an array from outside a class but I don't want it to be modifiable, so I used a simple get_array method. What I want to know if it's possible to call the function and choose an item from the array at the same time, something like this:

Something like this:

```
<?=get_array()["item1"]?>
```

I think this is possible in C++ and I'm wondering if there is a similar way to do it on php

Answer (score 1):

I think best practice is

```
$value  = get_array();
```

And then you can do

```
$value['key']
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible as of php 5.4.x. This is called **array dereferencing**.

http://php.net/array#language.types.array.syntax.array-func

Just the way you wrote it :

```
<?=get_array()["item1"]?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `before asking` you can just test.

From PHP 5.4 it's possible to do exactly that:

```
getSomeArray()['some_key']
```

Look [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88).

In < PHP 5.3, you'll need to use a temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
get_array($index){
    return $array[$index];
}
<?=get_array("item1")?>
```

Reshad's method is recommended, still this one looks good too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still new at this coding stuff. Would a mixed return help you?

```
function get_array($want=null)
{
if ($want==null)
{
return $arr;
}
else
{
loop through and get what you want
}
}
```